# Crear matriz bidimensional en c++

Tags: c++, matrices, teclado

¿Podrían ayudarme a modificar este código?

Pase toda la mañana intentando hacer que cumpla con este enunciado:

> Crea una matriz o arreglo bidimensional que contenga cuatro (04) columnas y las filas que tú indiques por teclado, las tres primeras columnas tendrán números consecutivos empezando del 1 y la 4ta columna será el resultado de multiplicar las tres columnas anteriores. El arreglo tendrá la siguiente forma:
>
> [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero nada, esto es lo único que logre hacer:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(){

int numeros[100][4], filas, columnas=4;

cout<<"Digite el numero de filas: ";
cin>>filas;
    
for(int i=0;i<filas;i++){
    for(int j=0;j<columnas;j++){
        cout<<"Digite un numero ["<<i<<"]["<<j<<"]: ";
        cin>>numeros[i][j];
    }
}    
for(int i=0;i<filas;i++){
    for(int j=0;j<columnas;j++){
        
        cout<<numeros[i][j];
    }
    cout<<"\n";
}

return 0;
```

Gracias por su ayuda.

Answer (score 1):

Intenta algo como esto:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(){

  int numeros[100][4], filas, columnas=4, contador=1, multiplicacion=1;

  cout<<"Digite el numero de filas: ";
  cin>>filas;

  for(int i=0; i< filas; i++) {
    for(int j=0; j < columnas - 1; j++) {
      numeros[i][j] = contador;
      multiplicacion *= contador;
      contador++;
    }
    numeros[i][columnas-1] = multiplicacion;
    multiplicacion = 1;
  }

  for(int i=0;i<filas;i++) {
    for(int j=0;j<columnas;j++) {
      cout<<numeros[i][j]<<" ";
    }
    cout<<"\n";
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Salida:

```
Digite el numero de filas: 5
1 2 3 6 
4 5 6 120 
7 8 9 504 
10 11 12 1320 
13 14 15 2730
```

Estoy usando la variable `contador` que se incrementa en 1 con cada iteración en las columnas. La variable `multiplicacion` va a contener el resultado de multiplicar los valores para cada fila y es posteriormente reseteado a 1.

Comment: Muchas gracias.

Answer (score 1):

> Crea una matriz o arreglo bidimensional que contenga cuatro (04) columnas y las filas que tú indiques por teclado

Ahí te están pidiendo que uses memoria dinámica:

```
int filas;

cout << "Digite el numero de filas: ";
cin >> filas;

int** matriz = new int*[filas];
for( int i=0; i<filas; i++ )
  matriz[i] = new int[4];

// Resto del codigo
// ...

// Limpieza de la memoria
for( int i=0; i<filas; i++ )
  delete[] matriz[i];
delete[] matriz;
```

> las tres primeras columnas tendrán números consecutivos empezando del 1 y la 4ta columna será el resultado de multiplicar las tres columnas anteriores.

Es decir, no tienes que pedirle al usuario que introduzca ningún número adicional... todos son autocalculados:

```
for( int fila=0, numero=1; fila<filas; fila++ )
{
  int producto = 1;

  // Rellenamos las tres primeras columnas
  for( int columna=0; columna<3; columna++, numero++ )
  {
    matriz[fila][columna] = numero;
    producto *= numero;
  }

  // Y ahora la celda del producto
  matriz[fila][3] = producto ;
}
```

Y bueno, aunque no lo indica explícitamente en el ejercicio se supone que hay que mostrar la tabla:

```
for( int fila=0; fila<filas; fila++ )
{
  for( int columna=0; columna<4; columna++ )
    std::cout << matriz[fila][columna] << ' ';
  std::cout << '\n';
}
```

Aunque puedes dejarlo más chulo con las columnas correctamente alineadas... pero requiere un preproceso:

```
#include <iomanip>
#include <cmath>

int max = std::log10(matriz[filas-1][2])+1;

for( int fila=0; fila<filas; fila++ )
{
  for( int columna=0; columna<4; columna++ )
    std::cout << std::setw(max) << matriz[fila][columna] << ' ';
  std::cout << '\n';
}
```

`log10` permite calcular el número de dígitos de un número. ejemplo:

```
log10(100)  = 2
log10(999)  = 2.XXXX
log10(1000) = 3
```

Lo único que hay que hacer es sumarle uno para obtener el resultado correcto... ese será el ancho de todas las columnas. ¿Por qué consulto una celda en cuestión? La columna con más dígitos será la cuarta, pero como es la última me da igual el ancho que tenga... me interesan más las columas con los valores incrementales y de ellas la celda más interesante es la última, ya que será la que tenga el mayor número de dígitos.

Y con esto ya tienes el problema resuelto.

Answer (score 1):

> Crea una matriz o arreglo bidimensional que contenga cuatro (04) columnas y **las filas que tú indiques por teclado**.

Según entiendo en el enunciado, mientras que las columnas son fijas (4) las filas son variables. Dado que sabemos el tamaño determinado de las columnas usaremos un contenedor con elementos pre-fijados [`<array>`](http://es.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array). En cuanto a las filas, de tamaño indeterminado, usaremos un contenedor con elementos dinámicos y anexos [`<vector>`](http://es.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector), para facilitar su uso, con los alias pertinentes:

```
#include <vector>
#include <array>

using columnas_t = std::array<int, 4>;
using tabla_t = std::vector<columnas_t>;
```

Una vez conocido el número de filas, podemos hacer la operación de recogida de datos en la habitual estructura de doble bucle:

```
tabla_t::size_type filas{};
std::cout << "Filas: ";
std::cin >> filas;

tabla_t tabla(filas);

for (auto &fila : tabla)
{
    int producto{1};
    for (int indice = 0; indice < 3; ++indice)
    {
        std::cout << "Valor: " << indice;
        std::cin >> fila[indice];
        producto *= fila[indice];
    }
    fila[3] = producto;
}
```

Aprovechamos la recogida de datos para hacer la operación de multiplicación, así nos ahorramos repetir el bucle para multiplicar. He preparado el código de ejemplo y [puedes verlo funcionando](https://wandbox.org/permlink/05LXFsUg4uZmt4tD).

Comment: Yo añadiría que ese código solo compilará con C++11... recuerda que en las academias y en la universidad suelen utilizar ordenadores de la época de los romanos...

Comment: No es la primera vez que discutimos esto @eferion y mi opinión no va a cambiar: C++11 se aprobó hace 6 años, si una academia/universidad está usando un compilador anterior a C++11 no merece estar enseñando.

Comment: Lo se y opino lo mismo... pero la realidad es la que es... en mi clase teníamos equipos con msdos y no creo que hayan renovado todas las instalaciones de golpe

Comment: Así se va a quedar, el *Warning! C++11 o superior!* ya está en los comentarios.

Comment: Jajajaja, no es exigencia hacer caso a los comentarios, ya lo sabes ;)