# Ayuda para crear codigo en c++

Tags: c++, funciones, post, ide

Podrían ayudarme a realizar este código en c++ por favor?:

Crea una matriz o arreglo bidimensional que almacene números múltiplos de 7 consecutivos (7, 14, 21, 28, ...). El número de filas y columnas será ingresado por teclado. Se debe mostrar la sumatoria de los números ubicados en las cuatro esquinas del arreglo bidimensional.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std; 

int main(){
int numeros[100][100],filas,columnas, contador=1;


cout<<"Ingrese el numero de filas: ";
cin>>filas;
cout<<"ingrese el numero de columnas: ";
cin>>columnas;
for(int i=0; i< filas; i++){
    for (int j=0;j<columnas;j++){

        numeros[i][j] = contador*7;
        contador++;
    }
} 

for(int i=0;i<filas;i++) {
for(int j=0;j<columnas;j++) {
  cout<<numeros[i][j]<<" ";
}
cout<<"\n";
}
return 0;
}
```

Logre crear la matriz con números múltiplos de 7 pero no puedo hacer la sumatoria en las esquinas.

Gracias por la ayuda.

Comment: Edita la pregunta y agrega el código que has avanzado.

Comment: Ok, lo haré en breve

Comment: No entiendo el enunciado.

Answer (score 2):

> pero no puedo hacer la sumatoria en las esquinas.

Si la matriz tiene dimensiones `[filas]x[columnas]` entonces las esquinas estarán ubicadas en las coordenadas:

- (0,0)
- (0,columnas-1)
- (filas-1,0)
- (filas-1,columnas-1)

El sumatorio entonces es trivial:

```
int total = numeros[0][0]
          + numeros[0][columnas-1]
          + numeros[filas-1][0]
          + numeros[filas-1][columnas-1];
```

Comment: Creo que otro problema viene a ser con el tamaño de la matriz, que es siempre 100x100

Comment: @AntonioM lo se, pero es que eso ya se lo he explicado en [esta otra pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/86609/ayuda-con-matriz-en-c)

Answer (score 0):

A pesar de que la respuesta de eferion es correcta a la hora de realizar el cálculo de la suma, veo otro problema: la creación de la matriz se hace antes de conocer los tamaños, y es siempre de 100x100.

Por lo tanto si quieres 200 filas, te dará una violación de segmento cuando estés rellenando la matriz en la fila 101 y lo mismo con las columnas, para ello yo crearía la matriz una vez sepas las filas y las columnas:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std; 

int main(){
    int filas, columnas, contador=1;

    cout<<"Ingrese el numero de filas: ";
    cin>>filas;

    cout<<"ingrese el numero de columnas: ";
    cin>>columnas;

    int numeros[filas][columnas];

    for(int i=0; i< filas; i++){
        for (int j=0;j<columnas;j++){
            numeros[i][j] = contador*7;
            contador++;
        }
    } 

    for(int i=0;i<filas;i++) {
        for(int j=0;j<columnas;j++) {
            cout<<numeros[i][j]<<" ";
        }
        cout<<"\n";
    }
    // Respuesta de eferion
    int total = numeros[0][0]
      + numeros[0][columnas-1]
      + numeros[filas-1][0]
      + numeros[filas-1][columnas-1];

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: La pregunta versa sobre C++, y en este lenguaje los [VLA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable-length_array) (_Variable Length Array_) **no forman parte del estándar**, luego no es seguro que funcione para todos los compiladores